# getFieldState is not a function. Error form shadcn, React-Hook-Form

Tags: react-hook-form, react-tsx, shadcnui

Here is my form component file. facing issue but everything seems to ok.

```
import * as LabelPrimitive from '@radix-ui/react-label';
import { Slot } from '@radix-ui/react-slot';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Controller, ControllerProps, FieldPath, FieldValues, FormProvider, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

import { Label } from '@/components/ui/label';
import { cn } from '@/lib/utils';

const Form = FormProvider;

interface FormFieldContextValue<TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues, TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>> {
    name: TName;
}

const FormFieldContext = React.createContext<FormFieldContextValue>({} as FormFieldContextValue);

const FormField = <TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues, TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>>({
    ...props
}: ControllerProps<TFieldValues, TName>) => {
    return (
        <FormFieldContext.Provider value={{ name: props.name }}>
            <Controller {...props} />
        </FormFieldContext.Provider>
    );
};

const useFormField = () => {
    const fieldContext = React.useContext(FormFieldContext);
    const itemContext = React.useContext(FormItemContext);
    const { getFieldState, formState } = useFormContext();

    const fieldState = getFieldState(fieldContext.name, formState);

    if (!fieldContext) {
        throw new Error('useFormField should be used within <FormField>');
    }

    const { id } = itemContext;

    return {
        id,
        name: fieldContext.name,
        formItemId: `${id}-form-item`,
        formDescriptionId: `${id}-form-item-description`,
        formMessageId: `${id}-form-item-message`,
        ...fieldState,
    };
};

interface FormItemContextValue {
    id: string;
}

const FormItemContext = React.createContext<FormItemContextValue>({} as FormItemContextValue);

const FormItem = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => {
    const id = React.useId();

    return (
        <FormItemContext.Provider value={{ id }}>
            <div ref={ref} className={cn('space-y-2', className)} {...props} />
        </FormItemContext.Provider>
    );
});
FormItem.displayName = 'FormItem';

const FormLabel = React.forwardRef<React.ElementRef<typeof LabelPrimitive.Root>, React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof LabelPrimitive.Root>>(
    ({ className, ...props }, ref) => {
        const { error, formItemId } = useFormField();

        return <Label ref={ref} className={cn(error && 'text-destructive', className)} htmlFor={formItemId} {...props} />;
    }
);
FormLabel.displayName = 'FormLabel';

const FormControl = React.forwardRef<React.ElementRef<typeof Slot>, React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof Slot>>(({ ...props }, ref) => {
    const { error, formItemId, formDescriptionId, formMessageId } = useFormField();

    return (
        <Slot
            ref={ref}
            id={formItemId}
            aria-describedby={!error ? `${formDescriptionId}` : `${formDescriptionId} ${formMessageId}`}
            aria-invalid={!!error}
            {...props}
        />
    );
});
FormControl.displayName = 'FormControl';

const FormDescription = React.forwardRef<HTMLParagraphElement, React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => {
    const { formDescriptionId } = useFormField();

    return <p ref={ref} id={formDescriptionId} className={cn('text-sm text-muted-foreground', className)} {...props} />;
});
FormDescription.displayName = 'FormDescription';

const FormMessage = React.forwardRef<HTMLParagraphElement, React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>>(({ className, children, ...props }, ref) => {
    const { error, formMessageId } = useFormField();
    const body = error ? String(error?.message) : children;

    if (!body) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <p ref={ref} id={formMessageId} className={cn('text-sm font-medium text-destructive', className)} {...props}>
            {body}
        </p>
    );
});
FormMessage.displayName = 'FormMessage';

export { Form, FormControl, FormDescription, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormMessage, useFormField };
```

i created form and defined some fields. after some time i got the error " getFieldState is not a function" .
i don't know why it throws it . below are my package.json files and component where i wrote my code.

```
{
  "name": "handyhome",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint ./src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0 && yarn run type-check",
    "type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.344.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.2",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.11.24",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.19.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.18",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^43.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^16.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.35",
    "prettier": "^3.2.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "5.3.3",
    "vite": "^5.1.4",
    "vite-bundle-visualizer": "^1.0.0",
    "yarn-upgrade-all": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.1.1"
}
```

i tries to look for on google and docs. but nothing here to help. method is same as i doc's .

Comment: Can you please provide how you created form and defined fields?